# Firefox 24 not displaying webpage correctly

Tags: firefox

The image shows the programmr.com website as seen in my browser. It loaded correctly when I opened it for the first time. But it remains like this since then. It is the same on a private window. So it is not an issue of the cookies or cache. However, I can view the site correctly through anonymouse.org
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete your profile?  This behavior can be explained by an extension and/or specific code towards your region so try a proxy

Comment: Make sure JavaScript is enabled. And have you modified the about:config settings or installed any add-ons that could have done this (e.g. CSS blocking addons)?

Answer (score 1):

See if any of these steps work for you.

1. Disable hardware acceleration in Firefox.`Tools` - `Options` - `Advanced` - `General` - Browsing: `Use hardware acceleration when available`.
2. Clear the cache and the cookies from websites that cause problems. `Options` - `Advanced` - `Network` - Cached Web Content: `Clear Now`.
3. `Remove Cookies` from sites causing problems. `Tools` - `Options` - `Privacy` - Cookies: `Show Cookies`.
4. Close Firefox and start up in the Profile Manager as described in the following [**article**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Comment: I am not facing any problems with other websites. And I dont think clearing the cache or creating a profile will help, since it is the same with private browsing